# Hibernate 5.2.14 & C3P0: C3P0 using driver: null at URL: null (no XML at all)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, c3p0

my HibernateConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:core.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "com.test.core.domain" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.test.core.domain.dao")
public class HibernateConfiguration {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HibernateConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.test.core.domain.*" });
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(additionalProperties());
        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        ComboPooledDataSource сomboPooledDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        try {
            сomboPooledDataSource.setDriverClass(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")));
        } catch( PropertyVetoException pve ){
            logger.error("Cannot load datasource driver (" + env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName") +"): " + pve.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        сomboPooledDataSource.setJdbcUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.url")));
        сomboPooledDataSource.setUser(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("edrive.jdbc.user")));
        сomboPooledDataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("edrive.jdbc.pass")));

        сomboPooledDataSource.setMinPoolSize(20);
        сomboPooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(50);
        сomboPooledDataSource.setCheckoutTimeout(15);
        сomboPooledDataSource.setMaxStatements(0);
        сomboPooledDataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(30);

        return сomboPooledDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size", "1000");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", "2");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "false");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "EDRIVE");

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.CharSet", "utf8");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.characterEncoding", "utf8");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.useUnicode", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "after_transaction");

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "50");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", "500");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset", "false");

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries", "false");

        properties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");

        return properties;
    }
}
```

Properties file:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://www:5434/edrived1

edrive.jdbc.user=services
edrive.jdbc.pass=*********
```

When I start my web app, I get following message and exception in the log:

> 2018-03-17 13:59:34 INFO  C3P0ConnectionProvider:117 - HHH010002: C3P0
>   using driver: null at URL: null 2018-03-17 13:59:34 INFO 
>   C3P0ConnectionProvider:118 - HHH10001001: Connection properties:
>   {useUnicode=true, handling_mode=DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_HOLD,
>   CharSet=utf8, characterEncoding=utf8, release_mode=after_transaction}
>   2018-03-17 13:59:34 INFO  C3P0ConnectionProvider:121 - HHH10001003:
>   Autocommit mode: false 2018-03-17 13:59:34 WARN 
>   C3P0ConnectionProvider:124 - HHH10001006: No JDBC Driver class was
>   specified by property hibernate.connection.driver_class

...

> 2018-03-17 13:59:34 DEBUG BasicResourcePool:207 - An exception
>   occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.
>   java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)  at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:285)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:161)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:161)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:147)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:202)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)   at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

Here is a log of configuration of bean:

> 2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG PropertySourcesPropertyResolver:115 - Found
>   key 'jdbc.driverClassName' in PropertySource 'class path resource
>   [core.properties]' with value of type String 2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG
>   JndiTemplate:154 - Looking up JNDI object with name
>   [java:comp/env/jdbc.url] 2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG
>   JndiLocatorDelegate:102 - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc.url]
>   not found - trying original name [jdbc.url].
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc.url] is not bound in
>   this Context. Unable to find [jdbc.url]. 2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG
>   JndiTemplate:154 - Looking up JNDI object with name [jdbc.url]
>   2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG JndiPropertySource:101 - JNDI lookup for
>   name [jdbc.url] threw NamingException with message: Name [jdbc.url] is
>   not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc.url].. Returning null.
>   2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG PropertySourcesPropertyResolver:115 - Found
>   key 'jdbc.url' in PropertySource 'class path resource
>   [core.properties]' with value of type String 2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG
>   JndiTemplate:154 - Looking up JNDI object with name
>   [java:comp/env/edrive.jdbc.user] 2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG
>   JndiLocatorDelegate:102 - Converted JNDI name
>   [java:comp/env/edrive.jdbc.user] not found - trying original name
>   [edrive.jdbc.user]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name
>   [edrive.jdbc.user] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find
>   [edrive.jdbc.user]. 2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG JndiTemplate:154 -
>   Looking up JNDI object with name [edrive.jdbc.user] 2018-03-17
>   14:09:50 DEBUG JndiPropertySource:101 - JNDI lookup for name
>   [edrive.jdbc.user] threw NamingException with message: Name
>   [edrive.jdbc.user] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find
>   [edrive.jdbc.user].. Returning null. 2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG
>   PropertySourcesPropertyResolver:115 - Found key 'edrive.jdbc.user' in
>   PropertySource 'class path resource [core.properties]' with value of
>   type String 2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG JndiTemplate:154 - Looking up
>   JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/edrive.jdbc.pass] 2018-03-17
>   14:09:50 DEBUG JndiLocatorDelegate:102 - Converted JNDI name
>   [java:comp/env/edrive.jdbc.pass] not found - trying original name
>   [edrive.jdbc.pass]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name
>   [edrive.jdbc.pass] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find
>   [edrive.jdbc.pass]. 2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG JndiTemplate:154 -
>   Looking up JNDI object with name [edrive.jdbc.pass] 2018-03-17
>   14:09:50 DEBUG JndiPropertySource:101 - JNDI lookup for name
>   [edrive.jdbc.pass] threw NamingException with message: Name
>   [edrive.jdbc.pass] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find
>   [edrive.jdbc.pass].. Returning null. 2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG
>   PropertySourcesPropertyResolver:115 - Found key 'edrive.jdbc.pass' in
>   PropertySource 'class path resource [core.properties]' with value of
>   type String 2018-03-17 14:09:50 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:573 -
>   Eagerly caching bean 'dataSource' to allow for resolving potential
>   circular references

All properties are set in the corresponding core.properties file, database is alive and works fine with Hibernate 5.1 and XML config. Now I would like to migrate to Spring Boot 2, so, I need to convert my configurations to XMLless stuff. What is going wrong with my current implementation?

Comment: Please include your properties file. And try to use `@PropertySource({ "classpath:/core.properties" })`

Comment: I've added properties file. According to log, all properties are available.

Comment: The problem seems to be one of you configuring connections in two distinct ways. You are initializing a datasource, but then also instructing Hibernate to configure a `C3P0ConnectionProvider`. If I'm not mistaken, you should remove the property `hibernate.connection.provider_class` and you should be good. Not 100% sure, because I usually don't configure it like that.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I removed this property and now app is able to connect. Now going to refactor queries (I mean Query which is deprecated in 5.2.14). Thanks a lot!